# Really high memory usage with almost no plugins -- could Arabic / Hebrew text be a factor?

Tags: memory

I've got a fairly small site with literally almost zero plugins (Importer, W3 Total Cache) and not that many pages or media assets but it's running a huge amount of memory (regularly 33MB plus).

The only thing I can think of is that this is because about 12 of the 20 pages use RTL languages.  My workflow for handling those is Word document / Google Drive doc to Sublime Text 2 to Wordpress editor. Anyone have any experience with this that might be able to help out? Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't call 33MB "high memory use". Last I checked 32MB was the minimum RAM for a WordPress install (64MB for multisite).

Comment: Hmm ok maybe I'm mistaken.  I've been lead to believe by the TPC Memory Usage docs that the ranges I'm getting for load averages are really high. Also I was getting 500 internal server errors earlier, which lead me to believe it was maxing out the memory allotment.

Comment: I would worry about the 500 errors but I don't think the memory usage is excessive.

Answer (score 1):

MO files (the translations) *are* memory expensive, especially for languages whose characters need multiple bytes for each – like Arabic, Hebrew, Chinese and so on.

So an increased memory usage is normal when you are using translated text. But 33 MB is really not that much. I wouldn’t worry about that. More important are sudden spikes in usage, monitor the values over a longer time. These are usually not a result of translations.